# WebSocket React Native Invalid error: Invalid Sec-WebSocket-Accept response

Tags: spring, spring-boot, react-native, websocket, spring-websocket

I am receiving an Invalid `Sec-WebSocket-Accept` response when client (running on a simulator) tries to establish connection to the server. My server is written in `Spring Boot` - `java` (`websocket`), client react native. I am using `WebSocket` to establish the connection to the server. This is what my client code looks like

```
  const client = new WebSocketClient('ws://localhost:5000/websocket');
```

Result:

```
Event {
  "isTrusted": false,
  "message": "Invalid Sec-WebSocket-Accept response",
}
```

I have tried everything but I keep getting this error. I tested the connection to a mock server `ws://echo.websocket.events/` and it works fine - I am confused on what I am doing wrong. I also tested this with `ws://10.0.2.2:5000/websocket` and i get

```
Event {
  "isTrusted": false,
  "message": "The operation couldn’t be completed. Connection refused",
}
```

NOTE: everything works fine on a browser

Comment: I'm pretty new to websockets, but in my case changing "ws://" to "wss://" on the server URL apparently solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

change `ws://domainname` to `wss://domainname` this works for me.